# Overhead of declaring a reference to the pointed-by value of a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Suppose I have a function which takes a pointer to an argument.

```
void foo(Info* bar) {

}
```

If I, instead of dereferencing bar any time I need its value, do this at the beginning of the function's code:

```
Info& i_val = *Info;
```

Am I introducing any particular kind of (noticeable) overhead by doing this? Or it will be the same as if I just were dereferencing the pointer around?

Please note that I won't be accepting any question that tells me this is a bad idea (without proper justification), complains about the use of raw pointers in a C++ codebase.

Also please note that I can't change the function's signature.

Comment: Can you explain why you pass a pointer instead of a reference to begin with? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: "Also please note that I can't change the function's signature". That's because I can't change the public API at this point, but I'd like the code to be clearer (avoid *s and ->s all around the place).

Comment: When you enable compiler optimization it can often do what you intent with the reference. In general I experienced that optimization at that level id done best by the compiler. Dont't worry, let optimze.

Comment: References are merely a syntactical construct in C++, at runtime they are just plain pointers.  So you are just replacing one pointer with another one.  Intentionally creating *aliasing* is not a fantastic idea, you give the optimizer a much harder time to figure out that dereferencing the aliased pointer has no unintentional side-effects.  But modern compilers are pretty good at it and as long as you are consistent in only using i_val and never bar then it is fairly unlikely the code will run slower.  You have to profile to be sure.  Do watch out for UB if bar is nullptr.

Answer (score 4):

> Am I introducing any particular kind of (noticeable) overhead by doing this?

No. Reference handling is very efficient, so apart from storage in the automatic area for the reference itself you are not using any additional resources.

> Or it will be the same as if I just were dereferencing the pointer around?

The big difference between creating a reference and dereferencing the original pointer is what would happen when the pointer is reassigned. The reference would continue referencing the object to which `bar` was pointing at the time `i_val` has been created, while dereferencing `bar` directly would give you its current location.

Comment: The pointer is not going to change its value durin the function's lifetime, so the second caveat is not going to be a problem (even though it's worth noticing). To better express this the pointer should be declared as const at the function signature, too bad I can't change that right now.